# PostgreSQL Connection to the server has been lost

Tags: postgresql, server

I installed postgreSQL server on a raspberry pi 4 with raspbian buster. When I try to connect from local network i have no problems about idle time. When i try to connect from my static public ip I can send command but if I didn't send anything for more than 3 minutes, it appears this message "Connection to the server has been lost".
I tried to install ufw and disable it, I used DMZ, I tried to change keepalive_idle, but i have always the same problem. Please help me.
sometimes the error is

```
"ERROR: SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out"
```

(Note: always if I am connected from public IP)

Comment: Were you able to check your router?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the same issue from within your local network I assume the connection is being terminated by a network device sitting between the `client` and the `server` (a `router` most likely).

There are routers with small `TCP timeout` settings (such as *300* seconds) which is close to what you're experiencing.

Try to check (and increase if needed) the TCP timeout settings on your router (and any other devices you might have in between).

## Edit:

I tried to find some info on that device (seems to be Sercomm VD625) and it does not seem you can easily change TCP timeout settings (maybe via telnet/ssh if it supports it).

However, a simpler solution might be to avoid keeping an open connection to PostgreSQL if you will have large idle intervals; just connect when you need to and close the connection afterwards.

Comment: I can't change the TCP timeout, i tried to keep the port open with a script. It sends commands every 12 seconds. it doesn't work.
I tried to use OpenVPN and it works, but after 3 minutes the time to receive the command is longer than at the start but there isn't the timeout connection.

Comment: What router do you have?

Comment: ADSL TIM white one